# append php echo in javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery-select2

[This is image want to make selct2 function... thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYsFq.png) `.append($(<?php echo $property_address1;?>))` this is my javascript code that i want to append.. this is select2 function actually i want multiple select2 onchange fucntion is required...

```
    public function test($id = null)
    {
        $this->layout->set(
                array(
                    'property_address1' => $this->mdl_quotes->property_address1()
                     )
                 );
        $this->load->model('mdl_quotes');
        $this->layout->buffer('content', 'quotes/test'); 
        $this->layout->render();
    }
```

My controller function

```
function property_address1()
{
     $query = $this->db->query('SELECT host,price,city,property_thumbnail, apartments_type, contactnumber, contactperson,photographlinks,emailid, propertyaddress FROM tbl_contacts')->result();
     $output = '<select id="neww" class="property_add_ form-control">';


    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        //echo $row->location;
        $output .= "<option value='". $row->propertyaddress ."'";
        $output .= " data-propertyaddress='" . $row->propertyaddress ."'" ;
        $output .= " data-host_name='" . $row->host ."'" ;

        $output .= " data-apartments_type ='" . $row->apartments_type."'" ;

        $output .= " data-city ='" . $row->city."'" ;

        $output .= " data-property_thumbnail='" . $row->property_thumbnail."'" ;

        $output .= " data-price='" . $row->price."'" ;

        $output .= " data-contactperson='" . $row->contactperson ."'" ;
        // $output. = $row->pincode.", ".$row->city.", ".$row->location;
        $output .= " data-photographlinks='" . $row->photographlinks ."'" ;
        $output .= " data-emailid='" . $row->emailid ."'" ;
        $output .= " data-contactnumber='". $row->contactnumber . "'>" ;
        $output .=   $row->host . ' , '.$row->propertyaddress . ' ,'.$row->price. ' ,'.$row->apartments_type. ' , '. $row->contactperson . ' , ' . $row->contactnumber. "</option>";
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    //var_dump($output);
    return $output;

    }
```

Comment: thanks naim malek for edit

Comment: `.append($(<?php echo $property_address1;?>))`
It seems to be missing quote characters, should be `.append($("<?php echo $property_address1; ?>"))` or `.append($(<?php echo json_encode($property_address1); ?>))`

Comment: quyet i did that now its working thanks... how to make it select2 now ?

Comment: quyet thanks for commenting really helpful.... i just posted the pic at above please have a look i want that in select2 and i want multiple select2

Comment: `$output = '<select id="neww" class="property_add_ form-control" multiple="multiple" >;` ,for multiple selection add multiple parameter in select tag.

Comment: no Asif I want select2 function... not multiple... I want to choose one address than automatic price will fill ... I posted screenshot also at above... thanks Asif bro

Comment: but I use that multiple one but didn't work

Comment: @Failure, can you post your HTML and JS code in view-source mode?

Comment: what is view-source code ? how to do it ? @QuyetTran

Comment: @QuyetTran this is the updated one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955225/i-want-to-use-multiple-select2-onchange-function-in-a-dynamic-way