# i want to use multiple select2 onchange function in a dynamic way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

I want to put select2 function in my code but don't know where to put that `.select2()` function
i have this `.append($(<?php echo json_encode($property_address1); ?>))` 
my model `

```
   function property_address1()
   {
     $query = $this->db->query('SELECT host,price,city,property_thumbnail, apartments_type, contactnumber, contactperson,photographlinks,emailid, propertyaddress FROM tbl_contacts')->result();
     $output = '<select id="neww" class="property_add_ form-control">';


    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        //echo $row->location;
        $output .= "<option value='". $row->propertyaddress ."'";
        $output .= " data-propertyaddress='" . $row->propertyaddress ."'" ;
        $output .= " data-host_name='" . $row->host ."'" ;

        $output .= " data-apartments_type ='" . $row->apartments_type."'" ;

        $output .= " data-city ='" . $row->city."'" ;

        $output .= " data-property_thumbnail='" . $row->property_thumbnail."'" ;

        $output .= " data-price='" . $row->price."'" ;

        $output .= " data-contactperson='" . $row->contactperson ."'" ;
        // $output. = $row->pincode.", ".$row->city.", ".$row->location;
        $output .= " data-photographlinks='" . $row->photographlinks ."'" ;
        $output .= " data-emailid='" . $row->emailid ."'" ;
        $output .= " data-contactnumber='". $row->contactnumber . "'>" ;
        $output .=   $row->host . ' , '.$row->propertyaddress . ' ,'.$row->price. ' ,'.$row->apartments_type. ' , '. $row->contactperson . ' , ' . $row->contactnumber. "</option>";
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    //var_dump($output);
    return $output;

    }`
```

my controller

```
  public function test($id = null)
    {
        $this->layout->set(
                array(
                    'property_address1' => $this->mdl_quotes->property_address1()
                     )
                 );
        $this->load->model('mdl_quotes');
        $this->layout->buffer('content', 'quotes/test'); 
        $this->layout->render();
    }
```

[Dhaval Panchal check this updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcooe.png)

[This is screenshot for better understanding.. please have a look Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMbgz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert CSS & JS file in your page then after JS file insert this code in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#neww').select2();
    });
</script>
```

To update options, see below code.

```
var option = new Option("text", "id");
$("#neww").append(option);
$("#neww").trigger("change");
```

Comment: it's generating two select2 when I click append button.... i need one select2 at one click please have a look on image... i upload at above in question area thanks dhaval

Comment: @Failure Please check if CSS file included successfully or not.

Comment: first select2 is opening and working fine onchange function... but secong select2 is not opening... it coming dynamically from append can you please help me out ??

Comment: @Failure Great then now you only need to update select2 rather than init again.

Comment: how to update select2 ? `$('.row-container:last').find("#new_").attr("id",locationId);` something here ?

Comment: @Mohsin $('#neww').trigger('change');

Comment: @Mohsin Is your code live or it is in local environment?

Comment: it is on local host

Comment: Let me know if you plan it to move on live environment so I can help you better.

Comment: I am on internship right now.. until I finish this task they will not put this on live ....

Comment: this is live id : mohsinshaikhms0@gmail.com Password : P@ssw0rd https://www.databagg.com/user/dash-board

Comment: Then how to proceed ?

Comment: go to link put my id and password then go to home their is three file... i am working on these file only.

Comment: after visiting to website you will see  MY DATA BAGG->home->now you will see 3 file