# first select2 is working but second select2 is not working... not opening second one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My second clone Select2 is not working only first works properly...
here is my code...
doing from a long time but i am stuck here in select2 function

```js
  var cont= 1
  $('#addButton').click(function(){
  var newId           = "Quotation_"+cont
  var locationId      = "new_"+cont
  var apt_nameId      = "apt_name"//+cont
  var choose_roomId   = "choose_room"//+cont
  var act_tariffId    = "act_tariff"//+cont
  var dcnt_tariffId   = "dcnt_tariff"//+cont
  var urlId           = "url"//+cont

  //$('h5').append("<hr>");
  $('h5').append($('.row-container:first').clone());
  $('.row-container:last').find("#Quotation_").attr("id",newId);
   $('.row-container:last').find("#new_").attr("id",locationId);
   
$(".property_add_").select2({
  "val": null,
  theme: "bootstrap",
    width: '100%', 
  
  placeholder: "Select Address"
}).select2("val", null);

 $('#new_').on(function() {

  //alert();

  //$('#property_address').val($(this).find(':selected').data('propertyaddress'));

  $('#apt_name').val($(this).find(':selected').data('apartments_type'));

});


//-------------------------------

  $('#new_').change(function( ) {
  $('#apt_name').val($(this).find(':selected').data('apartments_type'));

});
cont++

function property_address1()
   {
     $query = $this->db->query('SELECT host, apartments_type, propertyaddress FROM tbl_contacts')->result();
     $output = '<select id="new_" class="property_add_ form-control">';
    
    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        //echo $row->location;
        $output .= "<option value='". $row->propertyaddress ."'";
       
        $output .= " data-host_name='" . $row->host ."'" ;

        $output .= " data-apartments_type ='" . $row->apartments_type."'" ;

        $output .=   $row->host . ' , '.$row->propertyaddress . ' ,'.$row->price. ' ,'.$row->apartments_type. ' , '. $row->contactperson . ' , ' . $row->contactnumber. "</option>";
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    //var_dump($output);
    return $output;
   
    }
```

doing this from a long time but every time i miserably fail.. i try to do code with class,name,id all method are faill but at end i am asking on stackover flow maybe you help me out from disaster

Comment: Your code is poorly copied and poorly formatted. You have niether added proper DOM content related to your code nor required libraries. Half of your problem lies in making the code readable.

Comment: thanks @FaisalSayed for feedback.. this code `<div>
      <?php echo $property_address1;?>
       </div>` append two time when i do clone.. pleae have a look

Comment: this is more described please check this one..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955225/i-want-to-use-multiple-select2-onchange-function-in-a-dynamic-way